Short stays in Tenerife with Irish passport
I have an Irish passport and my husband a British passport. We want to visit Tenerife as regular as we can as we have property there. We will never stay longer that 49 days in one trip. Are we allowed to go for 7 weeks then return to England for a week or a month then back to Tenerife for another 7 weeks and continue this cycle indefinitely? I understand that if we want to stay longer than 3 months we will need a visa but this is not something we will be seeking to do. Any help would be much appreciated as we don't want to do anything wrong.

In general, one thing to remember when looking for information about this online is that there are two legal frameworks that are quite different, one for EU citizens and their family and one for everybody else. The experience of other British citizens who are not married to an EU citizen will not readily apply to your husband.
As long as your husband travels with you, an EU citizen, he doesn't need a visa and the Schengen maximum stay rules (no more than 90 days in any 180-day period) do not apply. The Canary Islands have a special status but they are part of the EU and freedom of movement definitely apply there. Unlike some other “outermost regions”, they are even part of the Schengen area.
Where things get a little more complicated is that if you intend to stay longer than 3 months, both of you are supposed to register with the Spanish authorities and obtain a Número de Identidad de Extranjero. Your husband should also get the local version of an “Article 10 residence card”. To get all that, since it doesn't sound like you will be working in Spain, you will need to prove you have sufficient ressources and health insurance (generic EU Commission info, Spanish government info).
The law is not explicit on that but it seems highly doubtful that leaving for a week in a rather blatant attempt to circumvent the rule would be enough to avoid this. On the other hand, if you do something like keeping a home in England and going to Tenerife for 3 months in the winter plus some incidental visits here and there, you could probably dispense with the formalities.
Importantly, if you are staying under the long residence rules, the EHIC / GHIC may not be enough to get health insurance. Students with an EHIC are covered, workers should be covered by the local system, pensioners are supposed to get a S1 document from the country that pays their pension but if you don't fall in any of these categories, you may have to get separate insurance, possibly some form of private insurance.

The special status  has to do with the customs free status of the Canary Islands. (Customs=deals with goods ; Immigration= deals with persons). The immigration rules of Spain (which Tenerife is a part of) therefore apply.

@MarkJohnson Not that the answer says otherwise but it's not exactly how this works. It's true in this case but it's not a given for all outermost regions. I didn't want to turn this answer in a primer on EU special territories but this status doesn't entail any specific set of rules but rather opens the possibility to opt out from some rules, including immigration rules. Some outermost regions are part of the Schengen area, some aren't (e.g. the French outermost regions). Conversely, Madeira and the Azores are in fact part of the EU VAT area.

On the other hand, all outermost regions are part of the EU, which means they are part of the customs union and EU citizens enjoy freedom of movement rights there. Only overseas countries and territories can restrict this (which is actually the reason Saint Barthélemy switched from being an OMR to an OCT).

You are an EU citizen and are allowed to stay in any EU country as long as you want (with minor conditions regarding not being a burden to the state, i.e. having enough resources and health coverage).
Your husband is a ”family member of an EU citizen” and has the same rights (in his case, in all EU countries but Ireland, because you're Irish) as long as he is travelling with you or to join you (in practice they never check that). He just needs evidence of his status (copy of your Irish passport and some sort of proof of your marriage).
You don’t need a visa or permit however long you want to stay or however often you travel.
If you planned to stay more than 3 months you would need to register your residence, and he would have to apply for a residence card (specifically, a "Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen"). Leaving for a week every 2 months wouldn't exempt you from that registration requirement if you stayed most of the year, but spending less than 6 months a year, spread over 4 different stays, none of them exceeding 49 days (as you stated your plans were), is nearly certainly OK (especially if you are just there to spend money you earned somewhere else -- things may be different if you intend to work there, but we have no idea of your situation or your plans in this regard).
Make sure you have your EHIC or GHIC card in case you need medical assistance.
(Edited again to match OP's plans, now 152 days/year spread over 4 stays, none of them longer than 49 days).

UK equivalent is GHIC.

Thanks for that. Are you only liable for taxes if you stay for 6 months or more throughout the year?

I don’t know the specifics for Spain, some countries have a lower threshold, but then tax treaties come into play, so it can be quite complex to know who you need to declare to and who you need to pay. This would be a question for https://expatriates.stackexchange.com

You're not really addressing the most difficult part of the question, which is whether leaving for a week every once in a while is an effective way to evade the requirement to register for stays longer than 3 months. Also voting to close and answering at the same time doesn't make much sense.

@Relaxed Ah, I had read the question too quickly, I was under the impression that it was 7 weeks in 7 weeks out which would probably be on the edge. Indeed with just a week out they would definitely be resident.

@Martha The UK has a double taxation agreement with Spain. It might be a good idea to get professional advice. See also GHIC/EHIC regarding health cover.

@Martha I adjusted by answer to better fit the 7 weeks in/1 week out periodicity which I had misread.

The Freedom of Movement rules also apply to Ireland (as apposed to the Schengen rules which do not).Two different set of rules.

Yes I suppose that's the crux of it whether a week back home is enough. I will only have to do this once a year tho as the rest of the time there are 1 or 2 months before travelling back to Tenerife. Thanks everyone, I really appreciate the advice.

@MarkJohnson I meant they do not apply to OP’s husband because OP is Irish, so freedom of movement doesn’t apply (but other Irish-specific rules may).

Thanks so much everyone for your advice. I'm frightened that our frequent short stays could be seen as abusing the system. We will stay in Tenerife for approximately 152 days out of 365. Never longer than 7 weeks at a time and usually with a couple of months break ( someone's longer)  except one visit where there will only be a week's break Could this be seen as abuse?

@Martha In terms of visas, permits, etc, you just cannot abuse the system. You are entitled to stay, live and work as often and as long as you want in any EU country thanks to the freedom of movement legislation in the EU (except Ireland for your husband, but other rules probably apply). You can decide to move to Tenerife tomorrow and stay there for 10 years if you want. The only thing is that depending on your circumstances, you may have to (a) register your residence there, (b) register with the taxman there, (c) file tax returns, (d) pay tax there, and ditto for national/healt insurance.

@Martha I'm a bit lost as to what exactly is your actual intention: in your original post it was 7 weeks in, 1 week out, indefinitely, now it's never longer than 7 weeks but only for a total of 152 (?) days per year. You can go as much and as long as you want, but how long and often you stay will determine where you have to pay taxes etc, that's it. You just don't want to end up with two different countries each saying you are resident and owe taxes to them, or requiring medical assistance and someone telling you are are not covered.

I'm so sorry for the confusion. Our plan is to visit Tenerife 4 times a year. Each visit will be for no longer than 7 weeks with a break in between ( once for a week but mostly a couple of months). When I posted to this website I also posted on Grow your Europe Advice who told me that as I was staying in Tenerife for 152 days out of 365 it could be seen as abusing the system and that my husband should seek a long stay type d Schengen visa even though we're never staying longer than 7 weeks.

@Martha I'm not sure what system you could abuse... The only question is whether you need to register your residence and apply for a residence card for him. You would be on a 7 weeks in 1 week out periodicity all year long, it would be clear that you would need to. Here I honestly don't think you need to, by IANAL. If you want to go ahead and register and apply, but other than a shiny card for him it won't change much.

@Martha When EES comes into effet he will need to clearly state he is an EU family member (so they don't count against 90/180) and when ETIAS arrives he will have to apply for one but it will be free. If he has the card it will be simpler (just show the card), but that's about it. Of course things are different if you later decide to spend more time in Tenerife and make it your main home. And if he wants Spanish citizenship (in 10 years), then yes, becoming a resident now is useful. But being half resident (for immigration purposes) half not (for tax purposes) is just useless complication.

Thanks so much for your advice. It's very much appreciated .

@Martha The advice you got on “Grow your Europe Advice” is just plain wrong. It would be right for a British citizen doing this alone but the spouse of an EU citizen will never need a D visa or be “abusing the system”. Instead, you may need to register, show you have health insurance, etc. but that's a lot easier than applying for a visa.

Thanks so much for that. You've put my mind at ease. I really appreciate it.

Could I ask you one final question that I really can't find the answer to anywhere: I know that you are allowed to stay up to 3 months without a visa. Is that 3 months continuous or if I go back to England for a while does that reset the clock so to speak?

@Martha Neither one of you ever needs a visa, however long you stay. You may need to register, and your husband may have to apply for a residence card if you stay longer than 3 months. EU law does not say anything about successive stays of less than 3 months, that's the whole point we have been dancing around with the variations of your plans. If you stay over half of the year, it's pretty darn certain that you are a resident, even if you leave for a week every 2 months. If you stay less than half of the year and never longer than 3 months, most probably not.

Thanks very much. I'm sorry. I just need to be clear in my own mind. Really appreciate your time and patience
